# Missing TypeScript typings with browserify + babelify + tsify

Tags: typescript, gulp, browserify, tsify

I am trying to migrate an Angular JavaScript (ES5) project to TypeScript 2.0 step by step and must admit I'm very struggling.
So first I changed the index.js to index.ts and used the [recommended method of installing typings](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/typescript/2016/06/15/the-future-of-declaration-files/) (`npm install --save @types/node`) instead of the old typings.json way.

Build setup uses `gulp` with `browserify` and now introducing `tsify` and `babelify` as suggested [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/gulp.html).

**browserify**

```
//...
.plugin(tsify)
.transform(babelify, {
      presets: ['es2015'],
      extensions: ['.ts', '.js']
})
//...
```

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
"files": [
    "assets/app/index.ts"
],
"compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false
}
}
```

However the build fails with:

> TypeScript error: .tmp/public/app/index.ts(4,15): Error TS2304: Cannot find name 'require'.

`tsify` seems not to copy the installed typings to the output dir, which causes the above error.
Any suggestion on how to solve the problem?

**EDIT**
Copying the *node_modules/@types* folder to the root of my C: drive eliminates the error, but I have no idea why...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case someone runs into the same problem:

Explictly adding the `typesRoot` option in **tsconfig.json** fixed it.

```
"typeRoots" : ["./node_modules/@types"]
```

This "should" be the default setting but for some reason it searches for the @types folder under C: drive root.

From TypeScript docs:

> If typesRoots is specified, only packages under typeRoots will be included.

Comment: What version of tsify are you using?

Comment: `"tsify": "^2.0.2"`

Comment: Could you create an [issue](https://github.com/TypeStrong/tsify/issues) for this? It looks like a bug. You should not have to specify `typeRoots`. Could you also include more of your configuration in the issue? I cannot see how a path like `.tmp/public/...` should end up in your error message.